# GROUP BY removes Rows with same values

Tags: mysql

for some reason (and I think I know why), when more than one row of *$activityday* have the same value, the other rows are no longer displayed. I think that it's because of the **group by**, but I can't be sure.

The *$activityday* is a number from 1 to 9 that represents an activity on that day. Table **venues_activity** takes that number and writes the name of the activity, while **group by** orders the activities in terms of importance.

Is there an alternative to get all of my rows shown? Thank you! :)

```
SELECT
venues.*,
venues_activity.ACTIVITY_EN
FROM venues
INNER JOIN venues_activity
ON $activityday = venues_activity.ID
LEFT JOIN events 
ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID  
AND start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' 
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
where events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL
AND VENUE_TYPE='1'
AND $closeday!='Closed'
AND $activityday!='9'
GROUP BY $activityday
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the [`ORDER BY` clause... not the `GROUP BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

`GROUP BY` is intended to do exactly what you describe... group duplicate values into a single row, which is intended to be used in conjunction with aggregate functions, such as `SUM`, `AVG`, or `COUNT`.

`ORDER BY` simply orders the results.

Comment: Wow, that never occurred to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` in instead of `group by`